# how do I get the Linearlayout id in the mainactivity class

Tags: android, xml, android-widget

I have created a widget where it has 4 buttons and one `linear layout`. I am trying to get the id of the linear layout. I used `findViewById` function but an error is coming saying `findViewById is undefined in MainActivity`.

Can somebody please tell me how do i get the id of the linear layout?
thanks

Comment: Can you show the `MainActivity` code and error log.

Comment: You need to give us much more information to help you. What do you mean by "get the id of the `LinearLayout`? And post your code of `MainActivity`.

Comment: at least provide your log here....if you can

Comment: Use getActivity().findViewById(R.id.yourid); or other context

Answer (score 0):

Define an `id` field in xml:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/<ID>"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Get reference of `LinearLayout` in `Activity`:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.<ID>);
```

**[EDIT]**
Make sure to call `findViewById` on the right context. Like if you are using a view, it should be, view.findViewById.